# Disable ActiveMQ demo component

Tags: activemq

Is it possible to disable the demo component of the Active MQ console? I have tried removing the following lines from `jetty.xml` but the `/demo`link still works.

```
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/demo" />
    <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/demo" />
    <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I am using Active MQ 5.5.1

Comment: posted in wrong group...

Answer (score 2):

In the end I deleted the folder `webapps/demo`, which has solved the problem.